# Using result of a thread in OnResume()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onresume

**My Problem:** Is it possible to prevent an activity to call `OnResume()` when it is being created? As I saw after the `OnCreate()` and `onStart()` method runs, the next one is the `onResume()`, although I only want to have it when I resume the activity from the paused state.

**Why do I need this:** I launch my activity (`FragmentActivity`, so lets say `OnPostResume()` ) starting with a thread which takes about 2-3s to be ready getting data from an external database. After the thread is done, I call a method which needs these data and I want to call it everytime that activity gets visible. The thread runs only when the FragmentActivity is created (`onCreate()`), and I cannot put the method into the `onResume()` because `onResume()` would be running way before the thread would finish its task. So it would receive not-ready data.

Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: If you are loading data, consider a [`Loader`](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of the exact application of this but I'll make a suggestion.

If you use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), you can send it off to get the data you need and in the `onPostExcecute()` method you can call your method that requires the data or update the view as needed.  (It runs on the UI thread)

If you happen to already have the data you need in certain scenarios you could also bypass the AsyncTask and directly update the view.

This AsyncTask can be triggered in the `onResume()` method.

If I'm missing something, please let me know and I can adjust my suggestion.

Comment: You are not missing anything, but i think the accepted answer provides an easier solution, and it works well so far. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I would argue that my answer is cleaner, more modular and easier to maintain in the long run.  But glad you got it working.

Comment: Actually I am just working on it, could you tell me it in more details? I dont really understand your solution, but I am roght now triggering AsyncTask in OnResume and it seems to be working.

Comment: I would have to see some of your code to go into any more detail than I've already provided.

Comment: I think i know what you mean, and I will accept your answer, since it works now very well, thanks!

Comment: Great!  And don't hesitate to ask if you have a specific question that will help clear things up further.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the purpose of this, but here's a possible solution:

If you only wish to get the even of onResume on states that didn't have the onCreate before, just use a flag.

In the onCreate, set it to true, in the onResume check the flag (and also set it to false). if it was true, it means the onCreate was called before.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would prefer to check if the result available, rather than always executing the getter-code in `onResume`. If the user somehow resumes your activity before the background thread is finished, you'd have a call on `onResume`, but don't want to display a result.

Maybe it would be a good idea to calculate/fetch the values in the thread, and let the thread return immediately (and cause the values to get filled in) if the values are already cached somewhere. That way you'd only have one entry point (the thread) for updating your UI instead of two (the thread and the `onResume` method).

Comment: These data are sensitive enough for the solution not to display them, however, that would works. But in this case I cant.